# How to add client certificates to the Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-webflux

I'm building a Spring WebClient which internally calls to REST API's which are hosted in different server. To do that I need to send public key (.cert) and private key (.key) to every request for the handshake.
I'm not sure how to do that with Spring WebClient.

I tried setting up WebClient, but struck at adding this peace of code

WebClient Builder

```
this.webCLient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://some-rest-api.com")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                .build();
```

Actual Call

```
this.webClient.get()
                .uri("/getData")
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    System.out.println(clientResponse);
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyClass.class);
                });
```

Since there were no certificates added to the request, I'm getting the handshake error on the log

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

How to add those certificates to the WebClient requests, so I don't get this error ? I have the certificates, but not sure how to add it.

Answer (score 14):

It took me some time to find the *missing* piece in Thomas' answer.

Here it is:

```
public static SslContext getTwoWaySslContext() {
        
    try(FileInputStream keyStoreFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(clientSslKeyStoreClassPath));
        FileInputStream trustStoreFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(clientSslTrustStoreClassPath));   
        ) {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFileInputStream, clientSslKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, clientSslKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        trustStore.load(trustStoreFileInputStream, clientSslTrustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            
        return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
            .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
            .build();
            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("An error has occurred: ", e);
    }
        
    return null;
}


HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslSpec -> sslSpec.sslContext(SslUtil.getTwoWaySslContext()));
ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder
    .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .build();
```

Enjoy!

Comment: How to create keyStoreFileInputStream  and trustStoreFileInputStream is it from .cer and .key

Answer (score 4):

taken from the documentation [Spring Webclient - Reactor Netty](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor)

To access the ssl configurations you need to supply a custom netty HttpClient with a custom sslContext.

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
        .forClient()
        // build your ssl context here
        .build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslSpec -> sslSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Firstly you need to create keystore with the required keys**

You can use Java [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html#GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549) or more user-friendly [keystore-explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

**2. Next you just need load it into `HttpClient`**

[Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/index.html) offers more convenient way of creating `SSLContext` and configuring mTLS:

With - [Apache HttpClient » 5.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5/5.2.1)

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfigConfiguration {

 @Value("${keystore.uri}")
 private Resource keystore;

 @Value("${keystore.password:}")
 private String password;

 @Bean
 public WebClient webClient() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
   SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
       .loadKeyMaterial(keystore.getURL(), password.toCharArray(), password.toCharArray())
       .build();

   Registry<TlsStrategy> registry = RegistryBuilder.<TlsStrategy>create()
       .register(URIScheme.HTTPS.getId(), new BasicClientTlsStrategy(sslContext))
       .build();

   CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
       .setConnectionManager(new PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager(registry))
       .build();

   return WebClient.builder()
       .clientConnector(new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
       .build();
 }
}
```

you can go even further and replace `HttpClient` with the one provided with Java:

Using - [Spring Web » 6.0.13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/6.0.13)

```java
...
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadKeyMaterial(keystore.getURL(), password.toCharArray(), password.toCharArray())
        .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .build();

    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new JdkClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();
  }
...
```

This page may come in handy when comparing these two options:
https://www.wiremock.io/post/java-http-client-comparison